# Length minimizing curves are geodesic segments

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, geodesic

I have a metric space $(X,d)$, a *geodesic arc* is defined to be a continuous function $\gamma : [a,b] \rightarrow X$, $a < b$, which is (globally) distance preserving and *geodesic segments* are defined to be images of geodesic arcs.

Given any curve (continuity is assumed) $\gamma: [a,b] \rightarrow X$ and a partition $P$
$$a = t_0 < t_1 < \cdots < t_m = b$$
of $[a,b]$ define
$$\ell(\gamma,P) = \sum_{i=1}^m d(\gamma(t_{i-1}),\gamma(t_i))$$
and we define the length of $\gamma$, denoted by $|\gamma|$ and which may be infinite, to be the supremum of all these sums for partitions $P$.

Because $a < b$ constitutes a partition of $[a,b]$, $|\gamma| \ge d(\gamma(a),\gamma(b))$.

Finally what I want to prove is the following:

*Let $\gamma : [a,b] \rightarrow X$ be a curve from $x$ to $y$ in $X$ with $x \neq y$. Then $|\gamma| = d(x,y)$ if and only if $\gamma$ maps $[a,b]$ onto a geodesic segment joining $x$ to $y$ and $d(x,\gamma(t))$ is an increasing function of $t$.*

I don't have either direction fully, what I have, my thoughts in general and some notes are:

- For the forward direction, that $|\gamma| = d(x,y)$ is the same as saying that equality holds in the triangle inequality for any partition of $[a,b]$; I can show that the same holds for any restriction of $\gamma$ and then using this I can show that $d(x,\gamma(t))$ is increasing. I thought maybe I could consider the reparametrisation of $\gamma$ achieved by affinely mapping $[a,b]$ to $[0,d(x,y)]$ hoping that this may give me a geodesic arc but I have gotten nowhere with this.
- For the opposite direction I've spent much less time thinking about it and have nothing at the moment.
- A useful fact might be that if $[x,y]$ and $[y,z]$ are geodesic segments joining $x$ to $y$ and $y$ to $z$ respectively, $[x,y] \cup [y,z]$ is a geodesic segment joining $x$ to $z$ if and only if $$d(x,y)+d(y,z)=d(x,z).$$
- This is from John G. Ratcliffe's Foundations of Hyperbolic Manifolds, Section 1.5.

Thank you.

Comment: In the statement you want to prove, I think it should say "non-decreasing" instead of "increasing".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First I will summarize the question using more definitions, to ease the discussion:

**Curves and Lengths**

(1) *Curves* are continuous functions from an interval of reals into the metric space.

(2) A *polygonal path* is a sequence of points (*vertices*) in the metric space.

(3) The *length of a polygonal path* is the sum of the point-to-point distances going from vertex to vertex along the polygonal path.

(4) The *length of a curve* is the supremum over lengths of polygonal paths having vertices in order along the curve.

(5) A *shortest path* is a curve whose length equals the distance between its endpoints.

**Geodesics**

(6) A *geodesic arc* is a distance-preserving curve.

(7) A *geodesic segment* is the range (in the metric space) of a geodesic arc.

(8) An *outward journey* is a curve for which the distance from the starting point is non-decreasing.

(9) A *geodesic journey* is an outward journey whose range is a geodesic segment.

**The Problem:**

***Prove that a geodesic journey is the same as a shortest path.***

**Proof**

To show that **every geodesic journey is a shortest path**, we need to show that the length of a geodesic journey equals the distance between its endpoints.

A geodesic journey $\beta$, by definition, corresponds to some geodesic arc $\gamma$, indeed by a weakly monotonic remapping of the function argument (corresponding to the distance traveled on the outward journey).
Note that $\beta$ and $\gamma$ have the same length.

Any geodesic arc is clearly a shortest path, since all polygonal paths going from end to end in fact have the same length, so the supremum is trivial.

Since the geodesic arc $\gamma$ is a shortest path, its length equals the distance between its endpoints.
Since $\beta$ has the same endpoints and same length, it is therefore also a shortest path.

To show that **every shortest path is a geodesic journey**, we will first show that every shortest path is an outward journey.

Indeed, if a curve $\gamma$ that goes from $A$ to $B$ is not an outward journey, then it must pass through a point $X$ and then $Y$, where $X$ is strictly farther from $A$ than $Y$ is.
This means that the polygonal path $AXYB$ is strictly longer than the polygonal path $AYB$, which is in turn at least the distance between $A$ and $B$ by the triangle inequality.
Thus any curve $\gamma$ which is not an outward journey is also not a shortest path.

All that remains is to show that the range of any shortest path $\delta$ is a geodesic segment.

For this, we need to show that there is a geodesic arc having the same range as $\delta$.

For each point on $\delta$, we consider its distance from the starting point.
Thanks to the continuity of curves, every distance from $0$ to the length $|\delta|$ of $\delta$ must occur for some point on $\delta$.
This provides a mapping $\rho$ from $[0,|\delta|]$ into the domain of $\delta$.

Thanks to $\delta$ being an outward journey, and the fact that distance $XY$ in a metric space is only zero when $X=Y$, we see that the mapping $\rho$ is continuous and has the same range as $\delta$.

All that remains, to show that $\rho$ is the geodesic arc we are looking for, is to show that $\rho$ is distance-preserving.

Consider two points, $X=\rho(x)$ and $Y=\rho(y)$, with $x<y$.
Let $A=\rho(0)$ and $B=\rho(|\delta|)$ be the endpoints of $\delta$ (and of $\rho$).
To show that $\rho$ is distance-preserving, we want to show that the distance $XY$ is given by $y-x$.
Since $\delta$ is a shortest path, all polygonal path lengths along $\delta$ must be of the same length, namely the distance $AB$, so in particular $AX+XY+YB=AY+YB$, so in other words $x+XY+YB=y+YB$, yielding $XY=y-x$.

So we are done: $\rho$ is a geodesic arc with the same range as shortest path $\delta$, showing that $\delta$, which as we saw must be an outward journey, is indeed a geodesic journey.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I quite like the terms you introduced. Just one point: your proof of the forward direction seemed a little unclear to me, I'm guessing what you meant is that the reparametrisation of $\beta$ to $[0,d]$ where $d$ is the length of $\beta$ must necessarily be a geodesic arc? This doesn't seem true to me, for example, consider a line segment in the euclidean plane and the map which first sits at one endpoint for a while and then traverses the line segment at unit speed, reparametrising this to $[0,\text{length of segment}]$ won't give a geodesic arc.

Comment: I have however (after being motivated by what you've written) been able to reason out a proof: Write down a partition $t_0,\dots,t_n$ of the domain of $\beta$ and the sum of the polygonal segments $d(\beta(t_{i-1}),\beta(t_i))$, each corresponds to $d(\gamma(t_{i-1}^\prime),\gamma(t_i^\prime))$ where $\gamma$ is a geodesic arc by assumption with the same range, by the outward journey assumption, $t_{i-1}^\prime \le t_i^\prime$ which gives the result using the geodesic arc assumption.

Comment: Thanks again, sorry I cannot upvote your answer - I don't yet have enough reputation.

Comment: I upvoted the op's question, if you want to upvote him as well, he will get enough rep to upvote your (excellent) answer.

Comment: @Santiago if you hit 15 you can upvote Matt's response; I got you started. Welcome to the site.

Comment: @Santiago The geodesic journey $\beta$ is a function $\beta:[t_0,t_1]\mapsto \mbox{range}(\gamma)$, and $\gamma$ similarly maps $\gamma:[s_0,s_1]\mapsto \mbox{range}(\gamma)$ but in a distance-preserving way. Since $\beta$ is an outward journey, the function $\mu(d)=D\!\left(\,\beta(t_0),\;\beta(t_0+d)\right)$ is non-decreasing (i.e. weakly monotonic), indeed, $\beta(t_0+d)=\gamma(s_0+\mu(d)).$ This was what I meant by the "weakly monotonic remapping of the function argument". (If this is what you were asking.) Glad you liked the terms -- I introduced them just to lessen my own confusion!

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks a lot for that, I need to think about the problem again (and I unfortunately don't have time right now) to properly remember the issue I had again, but I appreciate your response.

Also @AdamHughes thank you, appreciate it, I shall upvote now.